# android app is not exists in home button cache

Tags: android, caching, android-homebutton

I Develop An Android App And When I Run On Android 4.3 After Home Button Pressed App Is Not Exists In Applications Cache But When I Run It On Android 5 It Exists Correctly In Cache After Home Button Pressed ...
Please Help Me How Can I Solve This Problem?

Comment: post some code so we can help, right now nobody has any way of knowing how to help you...

Comment: my app has over 40 class and activity which part of code does need for this problem ? manifest file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it 
in my manifest for launcher activity was a android:excludeFromRecents="true"
and this was problem when i comment this line app keep correctly in cache when home button clicked